# error: classname does not name a type

Tags: c++, arrays, types, declaration

I'm an intermediate student starting on pointers.  I'm trying to store data in an array to be called by a search function later.   When I try to compile, I am told "error: retail does not name a type" and I don't understand what that means or how to fix it.

```
// ********************************************************
// Starting Out with C++                                  *
// From Control Stuctures through Objects                 *
// seventh edition                                        *
//                                                        *
// Chapter 8 Searching and Sorting Arrays                 *
//                                                        *
// Serendipity Booksellers Software Development           *
// Project — Part 8: A Problem-Solving Exercise           *
//                                                        *
// Multi-File Program                                     *
// ********************************************************
#include "bookinfo.h"
#include "cashier.h"
#include "invmenu.h"
#include "reports.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Constant for array sizes
const int SIZE = 20;
// Global Arrays
string bookTitle[SIZE];
string isbn[SIZE];
string author[SIZE];
string publisher[SIZE];
string dateAdded[SIZE];
int qtyOnHand[SIZE];
double wholesale[SIZE];
double retail[SIZE];

retail[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};

wholesale[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};

qtyOnHand[SIZE] = {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10};


dateAdded[0] = "1/1";
dateAdded[1] = "1/1";
dateAdded[2] = "2/1";
dateAdded[3] = "3/1";
dateAdded[4] = "4/1";
dateAdded[5] = "5/1";
dateAdded[6] = "6/1";
dateAdded[7] = "7/1";
dateAdded[8] = "8/1";
dateAdded[9] = "9/1";
dateAdded[10] = "10/1";
dateAdded[11] = "11/1";
dateAdded[12] = "12/1";
dateAdded[13] = "13/1";
dateAdded[14] = "14/1";
dateAdded[15] = "15/1";
dateAdded[16] = "16/1";
dateAdded[17] = "17/1";
dateAdded[18] = "18/1";
dateAdded[19] = "19/1";


author[0] = "0";
author[1] = "1";
author[2] = "2";
author[3] = "3";
author[4] = "4";
author[5] = "5";
author[6] = "6";
author[7] = "7";
author[8] = "8";
author[9] = "9";
author[10] = "10";
author[11] = "11";
author[12] = "12";
author[13] = "13";
author[14] = "14";
author[15] = "15";
author[16] = "16";
author[17] = "17";
author[18] = "18";
author[19] = "19";

bookTitle[0] = "0";
bookTitle[1] = "1";
bookTitle[2] = "2";
bookTitle[3] = "3";
bookTitle[4] = "4";
bookTitle[5] = "5";
bookTitle[6] = "6";
bookTitle[7] = "7";
bookTitle[8] = "8";
bookTitle[9] = "9";
bookTitle[10] = "10";
bookTitle[11] = "11";
bookTitle[12] = "12";
bookTitle[13] = "13";
bookTitle[14] = "14";
bookTitle[15] = "15";
bookTitle[16] = "16";
bookTitle[17] = "17";
bookTitle[18] = "18";
bookTitle[19] = "19";

isbn[0] = "0";
isbn[1] = "1";
isbn[2] = "2";
isbn[3] = "3";
isbn[4] = "4";
isbn[5] = "5";
isbn[6] = "6";
isbn[7] = "7";
isbn[8] = "8";
isbn[9] = "9";
isbn[10] = "10";
isbn[11] = "11";
isbn[12] = "12";
isbn[13] = "13";
isbn[14] = "14";
isbn[15] = "15";
isbn[16] = "16";
isbn[17] = "17";
isbn[18] = "18";
isbn[19] = "19";


int main()
{
    int choice = 0; // To hold the user's menu choice

    // Display the menu until the user selects item 4
    while (choice != 4)
    {
        cout << "Serendipity Booksellers\n";
        cout << "\tMain Menu\n\n";

        cout << "1.Cashier Module\n";
        cout << "2.Inventory Database Module\n";
        cout << "3.Report Module\n";
        cout << "4.Exit\n\n";

        // Get the menu choice as input from the user
        cout << "Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        // Validate the user's input
        while (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter a number in the range 1 - 4.\n";

            cout << "Enter Your Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
        }

        // Display a selection message
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    cashier();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    invMenu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    reports();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "\nYou selected item 4.\n";
                    break;
            }
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How am I failing to initialize the arrays?  Have I formatted my declarations incorrectly?

Comment: That "initialization" must go in a function or be part of the array definition, but holy cow, use a loop with `std::to_string` on the index. The other arrays can be filled with `std::fill` and `std::iota`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize an array with:

```
retail[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

You can initialize it when it is declared.

```
double retail[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

Or you can set the values using a for-loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
   retail[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that just noodling around and it worked! Glad to see I can stumble in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++11 initialization list is a blessing and match really well with std::vector:

**initializing**: 
`std::vector<double> retail {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};`
**assigning**: 
`std::vector<double> retail2;
retail2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};`

Try to avoid C array, vector have:
-Bound checks
-Automatic Memory Management (RAII, automatic grow, etc...)
-Iterator
-Interact well with the algorithms and adapter of STL

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem that you originally asked about has been solved, I think a bigger issue is the use of "parallel arrays" - this sort of data structure is a source of many bugs. It is much better to create a struct or class to describe each book entry and to them maintain a collection of these items, for instance

```
class BookEntry {

public:
    BookEntry(const std::string &title, const std::string &author, const std::string &isbn, double wholesalePrice, double retailPrice, const std::string &dateAdded, int quantityOnHand = 0)
        : title_m(title), author_m(author), isbn_m(isbn), wholesalePrice_m(wholesalePrice), retailPrice_m(retailPrice), dateAdded_m(dateAdded), quantityOnHand_m(quantityOnHand)
    {

    }

    std::string title_m;
    std::string author_m;
    std::string isbn_m;

    double retailPrice_m;
    double wholesalePrice_m;
    std::string dateAdded_m;

    int quantityOnHand_m;
};

// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "BookEntry.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    BookEntry bookEntries[] = {
            // Title,                        Author,           ISBN,             Wholesale,      Retail,      DateAdded,       QuantityOnHand
            { "The Hobbit",                  "J.R.R. Tolkein", "978-0547928227", 5.43,           9.77,        "1937-Sep-21",   1234 },
            { "The Fellowship of the Ring",  "J.R.R. Tolkein", "978-0547928210", 7.99,           10.67,       "1954-Jul-29",   4321 },
            { "The Two Towers",              "J.R.R. Tolkein", "978-0547928203", 8.01,           10.68,       "1954-Nov-11",   3214 },
            { "The Return of the King",      "J.R.R. Tolkein", "978-0547928197", 8.43,           10.77,       "1955-Oct-20",   2143 },
            { "The Talisman",                "Stephen King",   "978-1451697216", 4.31,            8.98,       "1984-Nov-08",   3333 }
    };


    for (auto &b : bookEntries) {
        std::cout << "Title: " << b.author_m << "; Author: " << b.author_m << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the data for initializing a `BookEntry` is now organized in a consistent way, so that it is much easier to identify a "record" in the array, and much harder to leave on element out, making the entire structure inconsistent.

In actual practice, you would probably refactor `BookEntry` to separate the books identity from its inventory and pricing information, and all of this would be kept in a database and initialized from there, but you'd still want a good data model in your program, not just a ton of parallel arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize retail like that, try this:

```
double retail[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

Although as you are using `c++` i would recomend trying to use `stl` types such as vectors.